# Regex - Replace \\n and \n in string by <br> but not \\\\n

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace all `\\n` and `\n` from a string by `<br>` but I dont want the `\\\\n` to be replaced.

Im trying with the following expression using negative lookbehind but it does not return the correct result because all the `"n"` and `"\"` are replaced:

```
import re
string = "this is a sample\\nstring\\\\ncontaining\nall cases\n\\n\n!"
re.sub(r"(?<!\\)([\\n\n]+)", r"<br>", string)
>>'this is a sample<br>stri<br>g<br>co<br>tai<br>i<br>g<br>all cases<br>!'
```

expected output

```
"this is a sample<br>string\\\\ncontaining<br>all cases<br><br><br>!"
```

Comment: Wait, do you want to replace multiple consecutive `\n` and LF    symbols with   1  `<br>`?

Comment: good point! multiple consecutive \n would be replaced by multiple consecutive <br>

Comment: I think your sample may not be working the way you think. If you print the original string the \\n is displayed on the same line as sample\nstring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the magic:

```
re.sub(r"(?<!\\)\\n|\n", "<br>", string)
```

Note: it will replace line breaks ("\n") and escaped line breaks ("\n" or r"\n"). It does not escape "\\n" (or r"\n").
"\\\n" (backslash + new line) becomes "\\< br>".

Maybe, what you really want is:

```
re.sub(r"(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\\n|\n", "\1<br>", string)
```

This replaces all new lines and all escaped n (r"\n"). r"\\n" is not replaced. r"\\\n" is again replaced (escaped backslash + escaped n).

Comment: I think the last one was supposed to be `re.sub(r"(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\n|\n", r"\1<br>", string)`. Interesting, it is supposed to match only unescaped `\n`  +1.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex has the character class `[\\n\n]` which matches `\`, `n`, or `\n`. Your lookbehind logic is correct, you just need to change your character class to a different subpattern: `\\{1,2}n`.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/1RhWkN/2)

```
(?<!\\)\\{1,2}n
```

- `(?<!\\)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes is not `\`
- `\\{1,2}` Match `\` once or twice
- `n` Match this literally

Replacement: `<br>`

Alternative: `(?<!\\)\\\\?n` as provided by [@revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) in the comments below the question

---

#### Usage in code

[See in use here](https://tio.run/##FYrNCsMgEITvPsXGk0II/bmm7YvsxYg0gq6yaw6l9NmtGQaGj/nqp@2F7r3HXAs34KAUw2Ps4kuuMQXD2rzWCdEifq/z7UfaKjkV3fYoMOpAXK4pIJI0jvTGEfKFmot0IrmUwDsJgjQepEmrOsRmeJFjM3rd@KlnkBku1vb@Bw)

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)\\{1,2}n")
s = r"this is a sample\\nstring\\\\ncontaining\nall cases\n\\n\n!"
print(r.sub("<br>", s, 0))
```

Result: `this is a sample<br>string\\\\ncontaining<br>all cases<br><br><br>!`

Comment: weird... in python the output is different: 'this is a sample<br>string<br>containing\nall cases\n<br>\n!'

Comment: @BelowtheRadar see the link. You probably didn't put `r` before your input string.

Comment: Although quantifiers seem to be more readable, I'd like `(?<!\\)\\\\?n`. You got my +1

Comment: I accepted Wiktor Stribiżew answer because it does not need to escape the string before use, but your solution is good too. +1

Comment: @BelowtheRadar to not have to use `r` before the input string you can use the regex `(?<!\\)(?:\\n|\n)`. I edited my answer to add that regex to it :)

Comment: You chose the hard way. @BelowtheRadar

Comment: That `(?<!\\)(?:\\n|\n)` is exactly what I added some 10 miniutes ago to my answer with explanations and a demo.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I apologize, I didn't see that in your answer. I'll remove as you did post first.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Adding a prefix `r` is right and simpler than all that stuff.

Comment: @revo in the demo maybe, but in real usecase I cant use `r` as the string is steamed, I would have to use `encode("string_escape")` and then the `\\\\n` is replaced by `\\\\\\\\\n`

Comment: Doesn't this work in your case `r'%s' % str`? @BelowtheRadar

Answer (score 0):

A regex version with a lookbehind is the shortest solution:

```
import re
s = "this is a sample\\nstring\\\\ncontaining\nall cases and one more\\n\nadded"
print(re.sub(r"(?<!\\)\\n|\n", "<br>", s))
## => this is a sample<br>string\\ncontaining<br>all cases and one more<br><br>added
```

See [this Pyhton demo](https://ideone.com/yX8ZHP).

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)\\n` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a `\` symbol, and then a `\n` 2-char string
- `\n` - an LF symbol.

Here is a [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bdmkn5/2) with the string from the OP.

An alternative is to match and capture `\\n` that you want to keep and then match `\n` and LF without capturing, and use a lambda expression as the replacement argument to implement custom replacement logic:

```
import re
s = "this is a sample\\nstring\\\\ncontaining\nall cases and one more\\n\nadded"
print(re.sub(r"(\\\\n)|\\n|\n", lambda x: r"<br>" if not x.group(1) else x.group(), s))
# => this is a sample<br>string\\ncontaining<br>all cases and one more<br><br>added
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Abgq0A).

Here, `(\\\\n)|\\n|\n` matches and captures `\\n` with `(\\\\n)` (that will be re-inserted into the result (`if not x.group(1) else x.group()` = if Group 1 matches, replace with its contents), or matches `\n` (with `\\n`) or LF (with `\n`) and they will be replaced with `<br>`.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Please check `r"(?<!\\)\\n|\n"` posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48949919/3832970). It might be a better solution, as `(?<!\\)(?:\\n|\n)`  won't match an LF in `s="abc\\\nhere"`. If you need to replace `\n` in that string, please accept dercolamann's solution. Still, my second solution with a lambda would work for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will find what you want, and than you can replace with `<br>`:
`(?<!\\)(\\)n|(?<!\\)(\\\\)n`